# Ajuste de ventana modal a formulario

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario en un modal, que tiene mucho espacio hacia la derecha y no sé como corregir
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_para_editar" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Editar</h4>
            </div>

                <div class="form-horizontal">                    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                                
                            </div>
                        </div>                                                                                          
                    </div> <!--cierra body-->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input type="button" value="Cerrar" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--cierra footer-->
                </div><!--cierra form-horizontal-->         
        </div> <!--cierra modal content-->
    </div> <!--cierra modal-dialog-->
</div> <!--cierra modal_para_editar-->
```

Cuando presento el mismo formulario dentro de la vista principal si se ajusta y no asigna el espacio como lo hace en la ventana modal

Comment: Cambia el `col-md-10` por `col-md-12` o simplemente quítalo.

Comment: lo que dice @JheymanMejia es cierto, también puesdes dejar el col-md-10 pero añadirle una clase margin: 0 auto; float: none; para que esté centrado.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que darle el ancho de las columnas que necesitas directamente al elemento que deseas colocar. Ten en cuenta que los paddings acumulados del modal, form-group, col, etc te restan espacio por lo que en este caso tendrás que dar un col-md-9 y no col-md-10 para que todo quede en una líena, si es eso lo que quieres:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_para_editar">boton</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_para_editar" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Editar</h4>
            </div>

                <div class="form-horizontal">                    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-12 col-md-2" })

                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-12 col-md-9" } })                                
                        </div>                                                                                          
                    </div> <!--cierra body-->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-auto">
                                <input type="button" value="Cerrar" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--cierra footer-->
                </div><!--cierra form-horizontal-->         
        </div> <!--cierra modal content-->
    </div> <!--cierra modal-dialog-->
</div> <!--cierra modal_para_editar-->
```